# GRASS GIS r.slope.aspect write errors

Tags: qgis, gdal, grass-gis, bash

I am running into an error running r.slope.aspect I have never seen before.  When I run it, I get the following output:

```
r.in.gdal complete. Raster map <dem> created.
WARNING: map [slope] - unable to write row 1269
WARNING: map [aspect] - unable to write row 1270
100%    
WARNING: error writing null row 1283
WARNING: error writing null row 1284
WARNING: error writing null row 1285
```

The "error writing null row" continues for a very long time.  I have been running this script many times and only recently am I starting to get this strange error.

```
echo "Running r.sun for day $DAY"
#Create new projection info
g.proj -c georef=$DEM
#Import Dem
g.mremove -f "*"
r.in.gdal input=$DEM output=dem
#Set Region
g.region -s rast=dem
#Calculate Slope and Aspect
r.slope.aspect elevation=dem slope=slope aspect=aspect
#Create flat map
r.mapcalc "zeros=if(dem>0,0,null())"
r.sun elevin=dem aspin=zeros slopein=zeros day=$DAY step=$STEPSIZE dist=$INTERVAL glob_rad=flat_total_sun
#Using dem and calculated slope and aspect, generate a solar insulation model
r.sun elevin=dem aspin=aspect slopein=slope day=$DAY step=$STEPSIZE dist=$INTERVAL insol_time=hours_sun glob_rad=total_sun
#Output files
r.out.gdal -c input=total_sun output=./global/daily/total_sun_day_${DAY}.tif
r.out.gdal -c input=flat_total_sun output=./global/daily    /flat_total_sun_day_${DAY}.tif
r.out.gdal -c input=hours_sun output=./insol/daily/hours_sun_day_${DAY}.tif
r.out.gdal -c input=slope output=./slope.tif
r.out.gdal -c input=aspect output=./aspect.tif
```

Comment: Maybe disk full? Which GRASS GIS version do you use?